# Prevent refresh when url returns from another app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trigger a bar-code scanner app from my webpage, and once the app is open, I am able to scan a bar-code and retrieve it via URL.

Now, I have multiple input fields on a page that the URL lands on. I take the scanned bar-code from the URL and put it inside the input fields.

The problem is that when the URL returns with the scanned bar-code, it refreshes the whole page therefore erasing all the previously entered values from input fields.

So, is there a way where I can retrieve the bar-code from the URL without refreshing the page (so that the input fields retain their values) or how can I retain the values entered in the input fields.

And I do not want to go to the server side of the equation. Please provide solutions workable only from the front-end side.

Below is the Fiddle I created. See if that is any help.

```
<input type="text" id="InputToOutput1" class="ScannedOutput"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="InputToOutput2" class="ScannedOutput"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="InputToOutput3" class="ScannedOutput"><br><br>
<a class="OpenScanner" href=""><button>Open Scanner</button></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/villageboy/cxr6srvo/

Comment: Might be that the `enter` key is 'pressed' by the scanner. You might want to try adding some code tor prevent the form being sent by it.

Comment: Yes, the  barcode scanner returns the scanned code via URL.

Comment: You could just use local sessionStorage. When user clicks on .OpenScanner, save  all input data to local storage and on page refresh if data exists in storage just repopulate the fields, its easy, shoudn't take too long http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: +Kristapsv This is exactly what I ended up using but didn't see your comment til late. I would mark your answer though if you just write it as an answer. Thanks again.